# Configure ember-cli globally to use yarn for new projects

Tags: ember-cli, yarnpkg

Is there any way to configure ember-cli globally to use yarn on new projects? A `ember new <project-name>` should use yarn without providing `--yarn` flag.

**Background information**

Recent versions of ember-cli uses yarn if

- a `yarn.lock` file is present in projects root or
- if `--yarn` flag is provided.

Since there can't be a `yarn.lock` before creating a new project, `--yarn` flag has to be used always on `ember new <project-name>` if yarn should be used.

If I got it correctly, ember-cli uses [yam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yam) for configuration by a `.ember-cli` file. But as far as I know, this one is also only available in a existing project and could not set global configuration.

**Motivation**

I could of course always remember to use `--yarn` flag on creating a new project, but often I forget about it and have to abort the command. I prefer yarn also on init cause it's a lot faster. Also if it's not used already on project generation, `yarn.lock` file is not part of the initial commit. It's simply annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.ember-cli can be configured both [globally](https://ember-cli.com/#runtime-configuration) and on a [per-package](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#Environments) basis

Global configuration is located in `$HOME/.ember-cli`

> Ember CLI’s runtime is configurable via a file named .ember-cli. The
>   JSON-formatted file, which must be placed in your home directory, can
>   include any command-line options whose names must be in camel case
>   form

Project only changes will be located in `/path/to/project/.ember-cli`.

> It is now also possible to override command line options by creating a
>   file in your app’s root directory called .ember-cli and placing
>   desired overrides in it.

Since you're wanting to have all newly created projects to use yarn, add the following to `$HOME/.ember-cli`

```
"yarn": true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally missed that part of docs. I accepted answer but please updated one point: At least for recent versions of ember-cli the option is named `yarn`. I also remember it was named `useYarn` or was this only for ember-try config?

Comment: You're right - it isn't "useYarn", it's just "yarn".  I assumed it was similar to pods, where the cli option is --pod and the .ember-cli option is "usePods".

I've updated my answer to reflect that.